# What is LPCTSTR?

Tags: c++, windows

what is `LPCTSTR` and `LPCTSTR`-like (for instance `HDC`) and what it does stand for?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569%28v=vs.60%29.aspx ?

Comment: This is why we just love Microsoft.

Comment: Those "types" always exhibit surprises, e.g. when you do `LPCSTR p, q;` and you wanted to have `const char *p, *q;`. Can you refuse to use them?

Comment: An abomination.

Comment: 64 bit porting of a 32-bit application requires knowledge of such terminologies

Comment: Related: [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Quoting Brian Kramer [on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/1b994ff3-da28-46a8-90ef-6c7fab8dcd21/lpctstr#e4e05bbe-7cb8-4321-97de-fcf1c435952e)

> `LPCTSTR` = **L**‌ong **P**‌ointer to a **C**‌onst
>   **T**‌CHAR **STR**‌ing  (Don't worry, a long pointer is the same as a pointer. There were two flavors of pointers under 16-bit
>   windows.)
>
> Here's the table:
>
> - `LPSTR` = `char*`
> - `LPCSTR` = `const char*`
> - `LPWSTR` = `wchar_t*`
> - `LPCWSTR` = `const wchar_t*`
> - `LPTSTR` = `char* or wchar_t*` depending on `_UNICODE`
> - `LPCTSTR` =  `const char* or const wchar_t*` depending on `_UNICODE`

Comment: Every time I see that type name I feel like cringing. There's just something about it that makes me uncomfortable. (+1 BTW)

Comment: When should I use this kind of pointer then?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine When an API tells you to. Just use the 'proper' types until then

Comment: "There were two flavors of pointers under 16-bit windows": Does the name come from back then? Some compilers used to call them far pointers...

Comment: be warned, there are lots of caveats to be aware of here.  wchar_t is a 16 bit type, but can be used to store both ucs2 and utf-16 encoded unicode characters.  utf-16 may use multiple wchar_t's to encode a single letter, ucs2 only supports a subset of the unicode characterset.  Which API functions you need to call also depend on the encoding used.

Comment: The worst is DWORD, which used to be a 32 bit double word, but nowadays is a 32 bit half word :-)

Comment: @MichaelShaw `WSTR` is always utf-16

Comment: `TCHAR` (and thus `xxTSTR`) depends on `UNICODE`, not `_UNICODE`. Those are usually defined to be the same, but one is from `tchar.h` and one is from `windows.h`. Also, the wide typedef for it is to `WCHAR`, which is `unsigned short`, not `wchar_t`. Under the C++ standard, those are different types, even though VC++ treats them the same depending on some compiler switches.

Answer (score 6):

There's no need to ever use any of the types relating to TCHAR.

Those types, all structure types that use them, and all related functions are mapped at compile time to an ANSI or UNICODE version (based on your project's configuration). ANSI versions typically have an A appended to the end of the name, and unicode versions append a W. You can use these explicitly if you prefer. MSDN will note this when necessary, for example it lists a MessageBoxIndirectA and MessageBoxIndirectW function here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645511(v=vs.85).aspx

Unless you are targeting Windows 9x, which lacked implementations of many unicode functions, there's no need to use the ANSI versions. If you are targeting Windows 9x, you can use TCHAR to build an ansi and unicode binary from the same codebase, as long as your code makes no assumptions about whether TCHAR is a char or wchar.

If you don't care about Windows 9x, I recommend configuring your project as unicode and treating TCHAR as identical to WCHAR. You can explicitly use the W functions and types if you prefer, but as long as you don't plan to run your project on Windows 9x, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

These types are documented at [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx) on MSDN:

> `LPCTSTR`
>
> An `LPCWSTR` if `UNICODE` is defined, an `LPCSTR` otherwise. For more information, see Windows Data Types for Strings.
>
> This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
>
> ```
> #ifdef UNICODE
>  typedef LPCWSTR LPCTSTR; 
> #else
>  typedef LPCSTR LPCTSTR;
> #endif
> ```

> `LPCWSTR`
>
> A pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 16-bit Unicode characters. For more information, see Character Sets Used By Fonts.
>
> This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR;
> ```

> `HDC`
>
> A handle to a [device context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183560.aspx) (DC).
>
> This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef HANDLE HDC;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was asked quite some time ago and I'm not trying to directly answer the exact original question, but as this particular Q/A has a decent rating I'd like to add a bit here for future readers. This has to do more specifically with the `Win32` `API` `typedefs` and how to understand them.

If anyone has ever done any Windows programming during the era of the 32bit machines from Windows 95 through and up to Windows 7-8 they understand and know that the `Win32` `API` is loaded with `typedefs` and that a majority of their functions and structures that are to be filled and used rely heavily on them.

---

Here is a basic windows program to give as a demonstration.

```
#include <Windows.h>

HWND ghMainWnd = 0;

bool InitWindowsApp( HINSTANCE, int show );
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
int run();

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int show ) {
    if ( !InitWindowsApp( hInstance, showCmd ) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return run();
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
    switch( msg ) {
        case WM_KEYDOWN: {
            if ( wParam == VK_ESCAPE ) {
                DestroyWindow( ghMainWnd );
            }
            return 0;
         }
         case WM_DESTROY: {
             PostQuitMessage(0);
             return 0;
         }
         default: {
             return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
         }
    }
}

bool InitWindowsApp( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow ) {

    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = WindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra       = NULL;
    wc.cbWndExtra       = NULL;
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    wc.hIconSm          = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wc.lpszMenuName     = NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszClassName    = L"Basic Window";
    wc.cbSize           = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX);

    if ( !RegisterClassEx( &wc ) ) {
        MessageBox( NULL, L"Register Class FAILED", NULL, NULL );
        return false;
    }

    ghMainWnd = CreateWindow( 
        L"Basic Window",
        L"Win32Basic",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL );
    if ( ghMainWnd == 0 ) {
        MessageBox( NULL, L"Window failed to create", L"Error", MB_OK );
        return false;
    }

    ShowWindow( ghMainWnd, nCmdShow );
    UpdateWindow( ghMainWnd );

    return true;    
}

int run() {
    MSG msg = {0};
    BOOL bReturn = 1;

    while( (bReturn = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) != 0 ) {
        if ( bReturn == -1 ) {
            MessageBox( NULL, L"GetMessage FAILED", L"Error", MB_OK );
            break;
        } else {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

This is barely enough code to render a windows application. This is the most basic setup to initialize the bare minimal properties to render a basic window and as you can see it is already loaded with `typedefs` from the `Win32` `api`.

---

Let's break it down by looking at the `WinMain` and `InitWindowsApp` functions: The first thing are the functions' parameters `HINSTANCE` and `PSTR`:

`WinMain` accepts a single `HINSTANCE` object while `InitWindowsApp` accepts two `HINSTANCE` objects a PSTR object or some other `typedef` string and an int.

I'll use the `InitWindowsApp` function here since it will give a description of the object in both functions.

The first `HINSTANCE` is defined as a **H**andle to an **INSTANCE** and this is the one that is most commonly used for the application. The second one is another `HANDLE` to a Previous *INSTANCE* which is rarely used anymore. It was kept around for legacy purpose in order to not have to change the `WinMain()` function signature that would break many already existing applications in the process. The third parameter is a **P**ointer to a **STR**ing.

So we have to ask our selves what is a `HANDLE`? If we look in the `Win32` `API` docs found here:[Windows Data Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types) we can easily look it up and see that it is defined as:

> A handle to an object. This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef PVOID HANDLE;
> ```

Now we have another `typedef`. What is a `PVOID`? Well it should be obvious but lets look that up in the same table...

> A pointer to any type. This is declared in WinNT.h
>
> ```
> typedef void *PVOID;
> ```

A `HANDLE` is used to declare many objects in the `Win32` `API` things such as:

- `HKEY`    - A handle to a registry key. Declared in WinDef.h

  - `typdef HANDLE HKEY;`
- `HKL`     - A handle to a locale identifier. Declared in WinDef.h

  - `typdef HANDLE HKL;`
- `HMENU`   - A handle to a menu. Declared in WinDef.h

  - `typdef HANDLE HMENU;`
- `HPEN`    - A handle to a pen. Declared in WinDef.h

  - `typedef HANDLE HPEN;`
- `HWND`    - A handle to a window. Declared in WinDef.h

  - `typedef HANDLE HWND;`
- ... and so on such as `HBRUSH`, `HCURSOR`, `HBITMAP`, `HDC`, `HDESK`, etc.

---

These are all `typedefs` that are declared using a `typedef` which is a `HANDLE` and the `HANDLE` itself is declared as a `typedef` from a `PVOID` which is also a `typedef` to a `void pointer`.

---

So when it comes to `LPCTSTR` we can find that in the same docs:

> It is defined as a `LPCWSTR` if `UNICODE` is defined or a `LPCSTR` otherwise.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
  typedef LPCWSTR LPCSTR;
#else
  typedef LPCSTR LPCTSTR;
#endif
```

---

So hopefully this will help as a guide as to how to understand the uses of `typedefs` especially with the *Windows Data Types* that can be found in the `Win32` `API`.

Comment: Many of the handle types are more strongly typed than just being `HANDLE` aliases if you activate the `STRICT` macro. Which is the default in new projects, I think.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It could be; but I wasn't trying to go into too much depth of the API and the strictness of the strongly typed aspects of the language. It was more of an overview of the Win32 API and its Data Types by the use of typedefs...